# Linq to Entities Query -

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables, **Submissions** and **Notations**.
**Submissions** has single entries, and **Notations** has multiple entries for the submissions linked via **AppID**.

What I am attempting to accomplish is to pull the submissions for a given date range, and the most recent notation to go with that submission.

I have managed to get all the data pulled; however, it is duplicating each submission record for every notation there is for the submission.

Here is my current code.  Can anyone help me figure this one out?

```
 var query = (from s in db.Submissions
             from n in db.notations
             from d in db.DCodes
             where s.AppID == (int) n.AppID
             && s.DCode == d.DCode1
             && s.received >= dts
             && s.received <= dte
             select new ApplicationTrackingSystem.customModels.Export
             {
                 AppID = s.AppID,
                 received = s.received,
                 //dcode = s.DCode, 
                 dcode = d.description,
                 firstName = s.firstName,
                 middleName = s.middleName,
                 lastName = s.lastName,
                 street = s.street,
                 city = s.city,
                 state = s.state,
                 zip = s.zip,
                 position = s.position,
                 hearAbout = s.hearAbout,
                 referredby = s.referredBy,
                 email = s.email,
                 commentID = n.commentID,
                 commentDate = n.commentDate,
                 user = n.userID,
                 comment = n.comment
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: How is it selecting only "most recent" Notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines. **Group** the notations by the submission and then retrieve only the **first ordering descending** by the `commentDate`:

```
var result = from s in db.Submissions
             join n in db.notations on s.AppID equals n.AppID
             where s.received >= dts && s.received <= dte
             group n by s into g
             let recentNotation = g.OrderDescendingBy(item => item.commentDate).First()
             select new ApplicationTrackingSystem.customModels.Export {
                 AppID = g.Key.AppId,
                 /* rest of s fields */,
                 commentID = recentNotation.commentID,
                 commentDate = recentNotation.commentDate,
                 user = recentNotation.userID,
                 comment = recentNotation.comment
             };
```

---

As Ivan corrected me it is nicer to use `GroupJoin` instead:

```
var result = from s in db.Submissions
             join n in db.notations on s.AppID equals n.AppID into g
             from n in g.OrderDescendingBy(item => item.commentDate).First()
             where s.received >= dts && s.received <= dte
             select new ApplicationTrackingSystem.customModels.Export {
                 AppID = g.Key.AppId,
                 /* rest of s fields */,
                 commentID = n.commentID,
                 commentDate = n.commentDate,
                 user = n.userID,
                 comment = n.comment
             };
```

Comment: `GroupBy`, really? Reinventing the `GroupJoin` :)

Comment: @GiladGreen Thank you very much.  I have been working on this for a couple of hours.  One thing I noticed is that I have lost the third table reference.  "from d in db.DCode"  how would I go about adding the third table into this solution?

Comment: @ChrisTurner - I just removed it so it is simpler to see the main point of the answer. Just add another join the way I joined `notations` in the first example :)

Comment: @GiladGreen - Thanks again.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: GiladGreen - A user pointed out an issue today.  Hopefully you can help me resolve it.  If there are no comments for the submission, it is not returning the submission.  Is there a way to make it return the submission with or without notes?

Comment: @Chris Turner - look at performi left joins with linq. SO' linq documentation is a good start - wrote stuff there about it myself. For more assistance then it'll have to be in a separate question and after you give it a try ;)

Comment: @GiladGreen  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Figured it out in a few minutes.  Much appreciated.  It wasn't your code that had the error, it was when I re-added the "join for d".